# Add "windows" to super user description?

Tags: discussion, status-declined

I had a tough time looking for the stack exchange Q&A for windows issues in order to post this question: [windows issue](https://superuser.com/questions/753710/how-to-install-windows-7-on-hp-pavilion-h8-1234-pc-with-missing-hp-dvd-a-dh16acs) . Finally someone directed me to this Q&A. The current description for SuperUsers reads:

> Super User
>
> For computer enthusiasts and power users.

I recommend that the community should add in the Super User description:

> Super User
>
> For computer enthusiasts, power users and window users.

Or something of a similar manner. Before anyone calls foul, just to be fair Ask Different has the following description:

> Ask Different
>
> For power users of Apple hardware and software.

Comment: Ask different's scope is _onle_ Apple hardware & software( iOS, iPod, iPad etc). So, it's not foul that it has that description

Comment: Superuser is for *all* generic computer hardware, irrespective of operating system.  If you can run a full spreadsheet application on it then chances are it is on topic here. While modern phone can run a spreadsheet they are usually not completely full featured and have been specifically excluded by the FAQ.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Super User is in no way a community specific to Windows products.

While we do discuss Windows-related problems, we also discuss pretty much any other operating system. So putting Windows into the description wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: What is the difference between Ask Different and SuperUser?

Comment: Ask Different is a site specific to Apple products, Super User isn't. You can ask questions about your iDevice on Ask Different, you can't on Super User.

Comment: Can we make a windows specific Q&A?

Comment: [You could try](http://area51.stackexchange.com), but we already cover Windows on [su], Windows Server on [sf] and Windows Phone on http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com

Comment: @linuxfreebird I do see your point though that it is not easily discoverable that [su] is the site to go to for general Windows-related questions. The proposed solution is just not appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I agree that my proposed solution may not be appropriate. I do believe there are other possible solutions that can be investigated to resolve this problem.

Comment: @linuxfreebird I'm not really seeing what "problem" exists. "Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users". Computers includes operatings systems. All of them, including Windows. Why go specific?